# Alternate array based on item value with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, alternate

What's the best way to alternate array based on value. For example, I've an array pattern :

This array must respect this pattern base on 'category' : article / quote / video / article / video... 
Without article : quote / video / quote / video...

I would like to have this result :

```
[
    [
        'title' => 'Foo 1',
        'category' => 'article'
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Foo 45',
        'category' => 'quote'
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Foo 45',
        'category' => 'video'
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Foo 2',
        'category' => 'article'
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Foo 25',
        'category' => 'quote'
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Foo 3',
        'category' => 'article'
    ]
];
```

Comment: What have you already tried ? Is there any logic that give that result ? Are you disposed to provide both that logic and your triesn or are we supposed to solve a puzzle before doing your work ?

Comment: Create 3 arrays, one for articles, one for quotes, and one for videos. Then use a loop that picks the next element from each array and pushes it onto the result.